# How to calculate word frequency in a list using C++?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, c++14

So I have some words in a file. I read them to a List then I'm trying to find the frequency of each word. My problem is that I have to follow a certain implementation for the list which isn't very flexible.
Here's the List class:

```
const int maxListSize = 50;

template<class T>
class List {
private:
    int numberOfElements;
    int currentPosition;
    T data[maxListSize];
public:
    List() {
        numberOfElements = 0;
        currentPosition = -1;
    }
    void insert(T element) {
        if (numberOfElements >= maxListSize) {
            cout << "List is Full" << endl;
            return;
        }
        data[numberOfElements] = element;
        numberOfElements++;
    }

    bool first(T &element) {
        if (numberOfElements == 0) {
            cout << "List is Empty" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            currentPosition = 0;
            element = data[currentPosition];
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool next(T &element) {
        //Check if the user called the first function
        if (currentPosition < 0) {
            cout << "Please call the first function before calling the next" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (currentPosition >= numberOfElements - 1) {
            //cout << "No next item" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        currentPosition++;
        element = data[currentPosition];
        return true;
    }
};
```

Assume my list is called names. How can I get the frequency of each word?

Comment: If you can *only* use the given `List` container then you could make a *list of pairs* like `List<std::pair<std::string, int>> names;` and when you get a new word, if it is already in the list, increment its associated `int` value as a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, given the unfortunate interface of List.

Initially I thought I would use `List<pair<string, int>>` but the `first` and `next` functions provide a copy of the element making it impossible to modify in place, so pointers it is!

This leaks memory. If not leaking is important to you then you could use smart pointers or attempt to free the memory. I figured simple might be better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int maxListSize = 50;

template<class T>
class List
{
private:
    int numberOfElements;
    int currentPosition;
    T data[maxListSize];
public:
    List()
    {
        numberOfElements = 0;
        currentPosition = -1;
    }
    void insert(T element)
    {
        if (numberOfElements >= maxListSize)
        {
            return;
        }
        data[numberOfElements] = element;
        numberOfElements++;
    }

    bool first(T &element)
    {
        if (numberOfElements == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPosition = 0;
            element = data[currentPosition];
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool next(T &element)
    {
        if (currentPosition < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (currentPosition >= numberOfElements - 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        currentPosition++;
        element = data[currentPosition];
        return true;
    }
};

using WordPair = std::pair<std::string, int>;
using WordList = List<WordPair*>;

void incrementCount(WordList &wl, const std::string& s)
{
    WordPair* item = nullptr;
    if (wl.first(item))
    {
        if (item->first == s)
        {
            ++(item->second);
            return;
        }
        while (wl.next(item))
        {
            if (item->first == s)
            {
                ++(item->second);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    wl.insert(new WordPair { s, 1 });
}

void printList(WordList &wl)
{
    WordPair *item = nullptr;
    if (wl.first(item))
    {
        std::cout << item->first << " : " << item->second << "\n";
        while (wl.next(item))
        {
            std::cout << item->first << " : " << item->second << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string words[10] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "one", 
        "two", "three", "two", "three", "three" };
    WordList wl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        incrementCount(wl, words[i]);
    }
    printList(wl);
}
```

Example: https://ideone.com/W4Slyq

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to hold duplicates? If so you can just loop through the list.

```
int count(T &element) {
    int numberOfDuplicates = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        if (data[i] == element) {
            numberOfDuplicates++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfDuplicates;
}
```